# Permutations as a product of transpositions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Show that any k-cycle σ in Sn, so σ=(a1 a2 a3 ... ak) can be written as a product of k-1 transpositions. Find two different ways to express σ as a product of k-1 transpositions.

Comment: Did you try with some small examples? Try breaking up $(3,2,1)$, and $(4,3,2,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

This proposition essentially says that you can switch $k$ things by switching $2 $ at a time. Notice that $(123) = (12)(13)$ and that $(1234) = (12)(13)(14)$. Now you can generalize.

Comment: Good, how can we write it in a different way? The problem also asks you to show a permutation with two factorizations.